# Playing audio on in ionic app with audio html5 tag enough?

Tags: angularjs, html, audio, ionic-framework

I'm trying to play audio in an ionic app. In the browser everthing works fine, but on the device no audio is played. But i think it plays the file, because the `ng-hide` works. I just hear nothing. Volume is up, i also tried with headphones.

Do i really need a plugin like `org.apache.cordova.media`?

I developed once an app and played a video, and there was the video tag enough.

What's my mistake?

This is my code:

```
.controller('AudioCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  var vid = document.getElementById("audio");
  vid.onended = function() {
    $timeout(function(){
       $scope.pause = true;
    }, 0);
  }
  $scope.pause = true;

  $scope.playAudio = function() {
      vid.play();
      $scope.pause = false;
  }

  $scope.pauseAudio = function() {
      vid.pause();
      $scope.pause = true;
  }

}
```

)

Markup:

```
  <audio id="audio">
    <source src="../audio/14.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  <img src="img/second/play.png" ng-click="playAudio()" ng-hide="!pause" alt="" id="s_play" class="animated bounceIn">
  <img src="img/second/pause.png" ng-click="pauseAudio()" ng-hide="pause" alt="" id="s_play" class="animated bounceIn">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the issue...

The path of the mp3 was wrong. It should be `"audio/14.mp3"`

Chrome can load it, but the device fails.